# Magento : Quickpay Payment Extension Doesn't Work at All in Frontend

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, third-party-module

it should go to payment page after select payment method and clicking place order button but it redirects to a blank page **example.com/quickpaypayment/payment/redirect** with nothing in it.

Comment: please edit question with `where you are struck` also try contacting extension team once......

Comment: it should go to payment page after select payment method and clicking place order button but it redirects to a blank page https://www.example.com/quickpaypayment/payment/redirect/ with nothing in it.
i have done all necessary configurations in backend panel using this link https://youtu.be/VQlPuJiIKFA

Comment: can you please check var/log files once

Comment: it give many errors like this
File does not exist: /var/www/abcd.com/public_html/skin/frontend/smartwave/iphone, referer: https://abcd.com/saphe-trafik-alarm.html?gclid=CMuy8fXErtICFVTcGQod4hUPAQ
File does not exist: /var/www/abcd.com/public_html/js/lib/cs.php, referer: http://wpoolsupply.com/cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi

Comment: please update your question with full details and errors, also check errors related to only this extension files, also if you dont want old log files, just delete them and try to place an order and than check new log files, than it will contain errors only related to that......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some problem with the block they used to call quickpaypayment/payment_redirect, 
so replace the code with following function in file
/app/code/community/Quickpay/Payment/controllers/PaymentController.php

```
public function redirectAction()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    $incrementId = $session->getLastRealOrderId();

    if ($incrementId === null) {
        Mage::throwException('No order increment id registered.');
    }

    //Save quote id in session for retrieval later
    $session->setQuickpayQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());

    /* Upgraded to version 10 of protocol */
    $payment = Mage::getModel('quickpaypayment/payment');

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $order->loadByIncrementId($payment->getCheckout()->getLastRealOrderId());

    $quickpay_state = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getQuickpayState();

    // Get array of selections
    if (isset($quickpay_state[0]) && $quickpay_state[0] == 'checkbox1') {
        $brandingId = $payment->getConfigData('brandingidchecked');
    } else {
        $brandingId = $payment->getConfigData('brandingid');
    }

    $parameters = array(
            "agreement_id"                 => $payment->getConfigData("agreementid"),
            "amount"                       => $order->getTotalDue() * 100,
            "continueurl"                  => Mage::getUrl('quickpaypayment/payment/success'),
            "cancelurl"                    => Mage::getUrl('quickpaypayment/payment/cancel'),
            "callbackurl"                  => Mage::getUrl('quickpaypayment/payment/callback'),
            "language"                     => $payment->calcLanguage(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()),
            "autocapture"                  => $payment->getConfigData('instantcapture'),
            "autofee"                      => $payment->getConfigData('transactionfee'),
            "payment_methods"              => $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getPaymentMethods(),
            "branding_id"                  => $brandingId,
            "google_analytics_tracking_id" => $payment->getConfigData('googleanalyticstracking'),
            "google_analytics_client_id"   => $payment->getConfigData('googleanalyticsclientid'),
            "customer_email"               => $order->getCustomerEmail() ?: '',
    );

    $result = Mage::helper('quickpaypayment')->qpCreatePayment($order);
    $result = Mage::helper('quickpaypayment')->qpCreatePaymentLink($result->id, $parameters);

    $paymentUrl = $result->url;

    $payment = Mage::getModel('quickpaypayment/payment');

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = $resource->getTableName('quickpaypayment_order_status');
    $connection->insert($table, array('ordernum' => $payment->getCheckout()->getLastRealOrderId()));

    $session->unsQuoteId();
    $session->unsRedirectUrl();

    $this->_redirectUrl($paymentUrl);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be payment module files are not found in theme folder.

Please check your module design file and put all file in base or theme folder same for skin file.

If this solution will not solve your problem try to check your controller and layout file for same handler

controller file location is

```
app/code/Compneyname/Modulename/controllers/paymentController.php
```

Layout file location is

```
app/design/package/theme/layout/....
app/design/base/default/layout/....
```

Also check controller action and layout handler